# MIPS - create a delay that "regulates" an 80MHz processor down to 1Hz

Tags: mips, delay

we got a task to implement a delay into a "running light" program. What i mean with that is, that we have a processor running at 80MHz but it should only output the light at a frequency of 1Hz. So I thought to implement a delay of 80.000 operations so that every 80.001 would be the light. And here is my try for that:

```
delay80M:
    li a0, 5000
    loopdelay:
    addi    a0, a0, -1
    nop
    addiu   sp, sp, -8 // Beispiel zur Stackverwendung (hier eigentlich nicht erforderlich)
    nop
    sw      s0, (sp)
    nop
    sw      s1,4(sp)
    nop
    lw      s1,4(sp)
    nop
    lw      s0, (sp)
    nop
    addiu   sp, sp, 8
    bgtz    a0, loopdelay
    jr      ra
    nop
```

Yet I'm not too sure if this is the most optimal way. Thanks in advance and have a nice day :)

Comment: Your asking for the optimal way to delay the processor?  What do you mean by optimal?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks like it will work, but it wastes a lot of power.
If you can setup a timer that interrupts the CPU once a second, you can use the MIPS `WAIT` instruction to stop the processor until the timer interrupt is received.